# Unity Problem, my camera goes up at the start of the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´ve followed a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1FYp1oOFIs&list=PLD_vBJjpCwJtrHIW1SS5_BNRk6KZJZ7_d&index=4
and the problem is when i start the game my camera moves up when it shouldnt.

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace BARR3TT
{
    public class CameraHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform targetTransform;
        public Transform cameraTransform;
        public Transform cameraPivotTransform;
        private Transform myTransform;
        private Vector3 cameraTransformPosition;
        private LayerMask ignoreLayers;
        private Vector3 cameraFollowVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        public static CameraHandler singleton;

        public float lookSpeed = 0.1f;
        public float followSpeed = 0.1f;
        public float pivotSpeed = 0.03f;

        private float targetPosition;
        private float defaultPosition;
        private float lookAngle;
        private float pivotAngle;
        public float minimumPivot = -35;
        public float maximumPivot = 35;

        private float cameraSphereRadius = 0.2f;
        public float cameraColisionOffset = 0.2f;
        public float minimumColisionOffset = 0.2f;

        private void Awake()
        {
            singleton = this;
            myTransform = transform;
            defaultPosition = cameraTransform.localPosition.z;
            ignoreLayers = ~(1 << 8 | 1 << 9 << 10);

        }

        public void FollowTarget(float delta)
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(myTransform.position, targetTransform.position, ref cameraFollowVelocity, delta / followSpeed);
            myTransform.position = targetPosition;

            HandleCameraCollision(delta);
        }

        public void HandleCameraRotation(float delta, float mouseXInput, float mouseYInput)
        {
            lookAngle += (mouseXInput * lookSpeed) / delta;
            pivotAngle -= (mouseYInput * pivotSpeed) / delta;
            pivotAngle = Mathf.Clamp(pivotAngle, minimumPivot, maximumPivot);

            Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;
            rotation.y = lookAngle;
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;

            rotation = Vector3.zero;
            rotation.x = pivotAngle;
             
            targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
            cameraPivotTransform.localRotation = targetRotation;

        }
        private void HandleCameraCollision(float delta)
        {
            targetPosition = defaultPosition;
            RaycastHit hit;
            Vector3 direction = cameraTransform.position - cameraPivotTransform.position;
            direction.Normalize();

            if(Physics.SphereCast(cameraPivotTransform.position, cameraSphereRadius, direction, out hit ,Mathf.Abs(targetPosition)))
            {
                float dis = Vector3.Distance(cameraPivotTransform.position, hit.point);
                targetPosition = -(dis - cameraColisionOffset);
            }

            if(Mathf.Abs(targetPosition)<minimumColisionOffset)
            {
                targetPosition = -minimumColisionOffset;
            }
            cameraTransformPosition.z = Mathf.Lerp(cameraTransform.localPosition.z, targetPosition, delta / 0.2f);
            cameraTransform.localPosition = cameraTransformPosition;
        }
    }

    
}
```

Ive checked every line and i dont see any mistakes the transforms are where they should be, i can kinda fix it adding some rotation in the x axis on the main camera but its still weird

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your camera has been attached to any script or if it is a child inside some objects. I think it is where the error comes from.
[image]

If the `Camera Holder` or `Camera Pivot` changes its direction so the `Main Camera` will be changed too.

Your code is very complicated and it doesn't have any comments. So that is why people when seeing your code are lazy to see, analyze and answer for you.

If you just begin with coding and I recommend that you need to build a good foundation first and then go to some difficult tutorials like those you followed. Don't follow step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: I see in the video it has the function `Fixed Update`, why yours does not have it?